# Stop nginx from redirecting to index.php

Tags: php, linux, redirect, nginx, raspbian

I have installed nginx, php5-fpm and then owncloud. I have edited nginx configuration files as given in this [tutorial](http://jankarres.de/2013/10/raspberry-pi-owncloud-server-installieren/). Now all my HTTP requests are redirected to index.php and I cannot cancel that! I have tried everything, but still no chance. I am a Linux and nginx beginner, so please bear with me.

This is the contents of my `/etc/nginx/siets-available/mysite`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www;
  index index.html index.htm;
}
```

Contents of `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
mysite
```

Contents of `/var/www`:

```
index.html tulips.png
```

index.html is a simple html with tulips.png inside. No redirection in HTML.

The problem is not on the PHP side, because when I stop php5-fpm service, the redirection still occurs.

I have walked the tutorial all backwards, but cannot restore the original state. All pages keep redirecting to index.php. Please help me to cancel that redirection.

Comment: what is the content of your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`?

Comment: what other files do you have inside sites-enabled? also what URL are u accessing this index.html with ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the tutorial,

Do you have a line that looks like this?

```
try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
```

This will attempt to serve the file specified by the URI in relation to the `root` (or `alias`). If the file is not found nginx will then redirect you to index.php.

I hope this helps, but we must be missing something...

P.S.

I'm assuming you've tried restarting Nginx (`sudo service nginx restart`). Nginx won't read the configuration files until you do this. (Or `sudo service nginx reload`).

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this to `website` and see if it works:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/
}
```

More details about try_files: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files.